# Angular UI-Router: Nested state/view displays route but not template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm currently using `Angular UI-Router 0.0.2` for routes/states in my angular app. In my app, I have both a *dashboard* and an *account* page - the dashboard displays app data; the account page displays user information.

When I have the `dashboard` and `account` state as two independent states, the route will change and the account page will display.

**This code works:**

```
routes = app.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'

$stateProvider.state( 'dashboard',
  url: '/'
  templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard/index.html"
  controller: 'DashboardIndexCtrl'
).state( 'account'
  url: '/account'
  templateUrl: "app/views/account/index.html"
  controller: 'AccountIndexCtrl'
)
```

However, whenever I make the `account` state as a nested stated of `dashboard`, only a blank screen displays.

**This code does not work:**

```
routes = app.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'

$stateProvider.state( 'dashboard',
  url: '/'
  templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard/index.html"
  controller: 'DashboardIndexCtrl'
).state( 'dashboard.account'
  url: 'account'
  templateUrl: "app/views/account/index.html"
  controller: 'AccountIndexCtrl'
)
```

My `dashboard/index.html` file:

```
%section.row-fluid
  .span12
    / directive
    %loginform
```

My `loginform` directive's template:

```
loginFormCtrl = app.controller 'LoginFormCtrl', ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $state, $log, User, Session) ->

  $rootScope.logged_in = false

  User.current().$promise.then (success) ->
    $log.info success
    $rootScope.current_user = success.user
    $rootScope.logged_in = true if success.user.user_name != null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `ui-view` to your dashboard/index.html template.